# Monitor AJAX requests from browser

Tags: ajax, browser, intercept

I'm browsing a webpage that seems to populate data through javascript. I want to use an extension for my browser that will allow me to see what requests are being made to what url and what data is returned from the request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox has a plugin called Firebug, or you can open its native console with Ctrl+Shift+K in newer versions. Chrome has developer tools with a Network tab.

Comment: my god i feel so dumb. this is perfect!

Comment: It happens. Anyway, Happy New Year to you (it's already arrived here), and happy hacking. ;)